# Basic Auth and JWT

Tags: node.js, authentication, nginx, basic-authentication, jwt

I'm currently running a Node.js application, with an API and files serving (I know nginx could handle it, but I wasn't supposed to use it at first).

I'm simply using it to have a simple basic auth, which happens to be not that simple.

Here is my nginx config:

```
  upstream nodejsapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:1337;
    keepalive 15;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    proxy_redirect off;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://nodejsapp;

      proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
      proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
  }
```

The `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` file is just `user:encryptedpassword` and is good.

With this config, when I go to my IP it:

- asks me the user and password
- starts to load the page
- (sometimes) asks again for user and password
- finishes to load the page

So far so good, even if it asked twice the password.

The Node.js app has a JWT authentication, when I sign in, the website reloads and from here, it asks indefinitely for the user and password (basic auth), as long I click on login. The JWT is in my local storage. If I click cancel on the basic auth prompt, the JWT is deleted and I'm logged out, and it... asks again for the basic auth.

This is on Chrome. With Firefox and Safari, after the JWT logging, it automatically deletes the token from the local storage (and I'm logged out).

It's pretty difficult to explain and I can't show you the website. In short the main problem is that the JWT (of the node.js app) is deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to mix Basic auth and JWT. I may be wrong but as far as I know, both methods use `Authorization` request header, so it's not surprising that they are conficting.

Comment: Yes, after some researches, I confirm it might be the problem

Comment: Don't think I can find any fix for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I realised that the problem was the **conflict** between Basic Auth and JWT (as @Curious suggested in the commend), and that they are both using the `Authorization` header, the solution was quite easy.

I configure my front end application to send the JWToken via a custom header, `**JWTAuthorization**`, so when the request hits the server, it contains both headers `Authorization` & `JWTAuthorization`. Then it's pretty simple, after the basic auth is passed, I just **replace the headers** (here on the Node.js application, based on Koa):

```
app.use(function *(next) {
  this.headers.authorization = this.headers.jwtauthorization;
  yield next;
});
```